# SignalR call OnDisconnect only after user closing the page/tab

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, signalr

So I'm using signalR to have online users list.
I used `stopCalled` to avoid that page refresh will be like disconnection, but now the user is never disconnecting..

```
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    var currentUser = manager.FindByName(Context.User.Identity.Name);
    string name = currentUser.NickName;
    if (!(stopCalled))
    {
        var item = users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Nick == name);
        if (item != null)
            users.Remove(item);
        userNames.Remove(name);
        Clients.All.hubReceived(users);
    }     
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}
```

The user should only disconnect only when clicking on button (log off button)
or when his closing the tab/page.
What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stopCalled` indicates whether the client [disconnected gracefully or not](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/releases/tag/2.1.0), so your current method will remove only those users where the connections is gone (ex: network drop).

For a list of all online users, **count** the number of connections for each user.

**OnConnected**

- if the user is not found in the list, add the user with `count = 1`
- if the user is in the list, increment the count

**OnDisconnected**

- decrease the count for that user
- if for that user `count = 0`, remove the user from the list

Comment: So I tried to do as you said.. but it doesn't work because postback causing the count to drop to 0, removing from the list and then connect again.. so the user is "blinking" from 0 to 1 when refreshing , that's my issuse :/

Comment: Ok. In this case, also use an `LastConnected` timestamp that is updated in `OnConnected` and `OnReconnected`. In `OnDisconnected`, do not remove the user if the count is zero. Implement an automatic job that runs every `x minutes` to remove the users with `count = 0` and `LastConnected` more then `x minutes` ago. Use an automatic job scheduler to do this, like [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler)

Comment: Or more easily, add a bit of latency in refreshing the current users, so it won't blink

Comment: I'm not sure how to do so, do you think it's possible to set timeout to a "remove user" jquery function, and check the user connections or something? I'm having trouble with that for over a week now.. the FluentScheduler looks bit too complicated to me, and i'm not sure what you meant on your second comment

Comment: C'mon, is not that hard. You got all you need, just put your back into it

Comment: I don't understand how to implement the FluentScheduler.. can I do it somehow without it?

Answer (score 0):

If a user is online, so it doesn't matter how many window he has opened.
You should keep track of online users by their connections `in database`.

If a user refreshes the window, you create a new connection, so previous connection finally become disconnected.

Something like this, I try to guess what you should code.

You should create a table in your database `OnlineUser` with columns `ConnectionId` and `UserId`

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    var onlineUserManager = NewOnlineUserManager<OnlineUser>(new OnlineUserStore<OnlineUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    var onlineUser = onlineUserManager.FindByConnectionId(Context.ConnectionId);

    if (onlineUser == null)
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var currentUser = manager.FindByName(Context.User.Identity.Name);

        onlineUser = new OnlineUser
        {
            ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId,
            UserId = currentUser.Id
        };

        onlineUserManager.Save(onlineUser);
    }

    return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    if (stopCalled)
    {
        var onlineUserManager = NewOnlineUserManager<OnlineUser>(new OnlineUserStore<OnlineUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var onlineUser = onlineUserManager.FindByConnectionId(Context.ConnectionId);

        if (onlineUser != null)
        {
            onlineUserManager.Remove(onlineUser);
        }
    }

    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}
```

You might want make some alteration to support multiple connections for one user.